# how to make an object float on water?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I watched a Youtube video.

Those blocks are floating on the water.

I think he used particle for the objects and fluid simulation for the water.

Is there anyone who know how he made the blocks floating on the water?

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFHR6Z1y5zM

Comment: you can use an ocean modifier and the use shrinkwrap modifier on a plane with target ocean and then copy location + rotation of that plane to you object -> Done. If you search here for float object or on yt you will find tutorials about it.